# Why would repeated measures random effects model values from polr() (in MASS package in R) be identical for all data points?

Tags: r, predict, random-effects

I have survey data involving two categorical IVs (Prompt_Condition and Response_Condition) of three levels each and one ordinal DV (value, a Likert-type ranking 1-7). There are 31 subjects who rated 18 dialogues. Each dialogue exhibits one of the nine possible combinations of the IVs. The data look like this:

> head(subset_data)

## A tibble: 6 × 7

```
 ID   Age Dialogue Response value Prompt_Condition Response_Condition
```

1     1    28 Q17      1        7     generic          null
2     1    28 Q17      2        7     generic          overt
3     1    28 Q17      3        5     generic          other
4     1    28 Q18      1        7     generic          null
5     1    28 Q18      2        6     generic          overt
6     1    28 Q18      3        1     generic          other

The data are plotted in the image:
[data plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSK7g.png)

I am interested in examining the model values for the random effects of repeated measures that polr() fits. polr is in the MASS package in R.

```
# Fit a polr model with only random effects
random_effects_model_polr <- polr(value ~ (1 | ID), data = subset_data)

# Generate predicted values
predicted_values <- predict(random_effects_model_polr, type = "probs")
```

I expect the model values from predict (which are log-odds of each of the levels of 'value') to be different for each subject but they are all identical for all subjects and all data points. Here is a bit of the output of predict. The whole table is the same row of odds.

> predicted_values
> 1      2      3      4     5     6     7
> 1   0.0878 0.0394 0.0789 0.0591 0.115 0.138 0.482
> 2   0.0878 0.0394 0.0789 0.0591 0.115 0.138 0.482
> 3   0.0878 0.0394 0.0789 0.0591 0.115 0.138 0.482
> 4   0.0878 0.0394 0.0789 0.0591 0.115 0.138 0.482
> 5   0.0878 0.0394 0.0789 0.0591 0.115 0.138 0.482

polr() doesn't seem to be correctly modeling the repeated measures effect or am I misunderstanding something? (I am new to R and Stackoverflow.)

Comment: MASS::polr cannot model random effects. You've made the same mistake explained here: [Why is my lm() model unaltered by addition of a random effect?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/582911/237901).

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps I'll try a package meant for repeated measures and ordinal DV such as repolr (but it requires a time stamp which my data don't have). I'll look at lme4. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: lme4 can handle random effects but, as far as I know, not multinomial outcomes. Should you be open to Bayesian analysis (and there is no good reason not to be), you can model your data with [brms](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/).